# HTML colspan and rowspan issue

Tags: html

I have an issue with HTML `colspan` & `rowspan`, I want to merge the first column (name) and last column (telephone) but it gave me unwanted result.
Here's what I want as result:

[image]

Here what I got:

[image]

My code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Name</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Age</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Middle name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>pre</th>
    <th>post</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>055</td>
    <td>5778541</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roben</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>050</td>
    <td>5577854</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add the css you are using?

Comment: it's plain HTML, didn't use any CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

change `rowspan` to `colspan` and fix the colspan's value

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Name</th>
    <th colspan="1">Age</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Middle name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>pre</th>
    <th>post</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>055</td>
    <td>5778541</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roben</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>050</td>
    <td>5577854</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, your code gave me the wanted result, I made some changes because I wanted the age column to have more space so I added <th rowspan="2">Age</th> , then delete <th></th> that you added. and it worked as I want! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From the second row you have to fill all coloms.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Name</th>
    <th rowspan="1">Age</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Middle name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>pre</th>
    <th>post</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>055</td>
    <td>5778541</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roben</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>050</td>
    <td>5577854</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, as I mentioned above I wanted the age column to have more space so I added <th rowspan="2">Age</th> , then delete <th></th> that you added.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add 4 empty Heading Tag Before Pre&post
like this code:

```
<table>
            <tr> 
                <th colspan="3">Name</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Age</th>
                <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>pre</th>
                <th>post</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>David</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>055</td>
                <td>5778541</td>  
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Roben</td>
                <td>Jill</td> 
                <td>Adam</td> 
                <td>35</td>
                <td>050</td>
                <td>5577854</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but your code shows me an empty 3 rows below first, middle & last name. I found a solution by doing  this:              <tr> 
                <th colspan="3">Name</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Age</th>
                <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>pre</th>
                <th>post</th>
            </tr>